# Spin/Helicity-Density Matrices in Particle Physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, density-operator, helicity

I am searching for literature explaining the Spin/Helicity-Density Matrix formalism in order to compute "spin-dependent" matrix elements and cross-sections in particle physics.

I would prefer if the source would contain minimal examples for elementary processes within QED or even the Standard Model.

Answer (score 1):

Up until now the most useful texts I found are:

- [1] "Spin Formalism and Applications to New Physics Searches", by Howard E. Haber (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9405376)
- [2] "Polarization Phenomena in Hadronic Reactions", by C. Bourrely, E. Leader and J. Soffer (https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(80)90017-4)
- [3] "Spin in Particle Physics", by E. Leader (https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511524455)
- [4] "Basics of Electron Positron Collisions", by F. M. Renard
- [5] "The Interactions of Hadrons", by H. Pilkuhn
- [6] "Elementary Particle Physics: Concepts and Phenomena", by O. Nachtmann
- [7] "Angular correlations of lepton pairs from vector boson and top quark decays in Monte Carlo simulations", by S. Frixione, E. Laenen, P. Motylinski and B.R. Webber (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0702198)

Ref. [1] gives a broad overview over spin formalisms used in particle physics including: Projection Operator Methods (POM), the Spinor-Helicity Method (SHM) and Density Matrix Techniques (DMT). The first two sections discussing POM and SHM are written in an introductory manner also including minimal examples. The section about DMTs is rather conceptional and does not really explain how to use DMT in practice. Ref. [1] also contains a lot of references to secondary literature¹, which I was up until now not able to read in detail.

The contents of Refs. [2,3] are very similar. They include the full construction of DMT and also examples for interactions of baryons and mesons, but no elementary Standard Model process. Hence, they do not really help to understand how exactly one would compute predictions for example in the Standard Model of particle physics for specific processes.

Refs. [4-6] describe and use density matrices in computations. Beeing rather old these texts probably need to be used with care.

The content of Ref. [7] is basically summarized in its title. I found it useful to read into the topic of spin-densities since it makes direct contact to the Narrow-Width-Approximation (Where the spin-density is used to keep spin-correlations while ignoring off-shell kinematics).

I am looking forward to additional answers that might hint towards even more useful texts :).